# ApolloGraphQL implement Shared Schema across a federated GraphQL service

Tags: graphql, apollo-federation

I'm currently following a tutorial that composes multiple subgraphs into a supergraph, which is great for separation of concerns. What I'm wondering is it possible to have multiple subgraphs split out contributing data to a shared schema.

So for example, within the tutorial

Gateway. Composed of Products subgraph, locations subgraph, reviews subgraph.

***What I'd like to achieve, wondering whether its even possible.***

Gateway, Composed of Products from one API, along with products from another API, along with products from another API

i.e, different micro services building the data, but a shared common data model for products used across them.

Within the docs I'm reading at present "By default, exactly one subgraph is responsible for resolving each field in your supergraph schema" - which suggests that it is possible? But at this point I'm not entirely sure, or even if graphQL is the right technology solution for my problem.